# g++ build output garbage

Tags: compiler-errors, g++

When using make for a C++ project, the compiler outputs errors and warnings like these:

```
../include/Position.h:63:11: error: ?.nterprocess?.in namespace ?.oost?.does not name a type
../include/Position.h:65:11: error: ?.nterprocess?.in namespace ?.oost?.does not name a type
../include/Position.h:67:11: error: ?.nterprocess?.in namespace ?.oost?.does not name a type
../include/Position.h:72:78: error: ?.hmManager?.has not been declared
../include/Position.h:89:3: error: ?.ositionMap?.does not name a type
../include/Position.h:101:3: error: ?.MemAllocator?.does not name a type
../include/Position.h:102:3: error: ?.ositionMap?.does not name a type
../include/Position.h:103:3: error: ?.ositionMap?.does not name a type
```

What's going on? How to get this output pretty again?

Comment: It's probably your terminal emulator. Is this local, or over SSH?

Comment: But this only happens with the compiler output. Everything else is ok.

Comment: Try to redirect output to a file. Use `2>` to redirect stdout and stderr.

Comment: In PuTTY, I would have to change the remote char set to UTF-8, and this would fix the issue.  It's probably only the compiler output you're noticing it on, because nothing else is using non-ASCII characters.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart : Thanks. Your suggestion works! Please post your comment as an answer so that I can flag it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably with your terminal emulator - are you using SSH?

I've often seen this due to character set translation in PuTTY. It defaults to "Latin-1, West Europe", but the server appears to be using UTF-8.  Changing this setting seems to fix things for me.

[image]

Your compiler is probably the only thing outputting non-ASCII characters, so this is the most common place where this problem is recognized.